# What purpose do Sy's pictures of the little girl serve in "One hour photo"?

Tags: plot-explanation, one-hour-photo

In the movie, "One hour photo", Sy takes many pictures of a little girl and gets them developed at his own shop. Like the police officer observed, Sy knew they'd get to Bill and he'll set the Police after him. Which did happen, and was directly the reason he was tracked down and arrested.

Unlike the officer's suspicion, it doesn't seem like it was a part of a bigger master plan at all! If he hadn't done that bit, he could have gone free after traumatising Maya and Will. What purpose did Sy think it might serve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a threat says [**Wikipedia.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Hour_Photo)

> The next day, his boss **Bill (Gary Cole) fires him** [Sy] for a large amount of inexplicable additional prints. ...
>
> ..Sy follows and takes pictures of Bill's young daughter, and **sends them to Bill as a threat**.

Comment: Yes, which couldn't have gone any other way other than getting arrested, given his next steps. He didn't harm the girl, nor leave the vicinity, nor go incognito! So he just acted on instinct without giving it much thought?

Comment: Seems like it. He's not rational anyway and this is further indication.